# Advanced WSSecurityAction with two signature

Tags: java, cxf, interceptor, ws-security

I need to provide a timeStamp and two signature action with different features,
when we put two signature it understand only first
how we could handle it in cxf?

Answer (score 0):

we should provide custom action

**http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html**

```
<constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature 12345"/>              
                <entry key="wss4j.action.map">
                <map key-type="java.lang.Integer" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                        <entry key="12345" value-ref="customSignature"/>
                </map>
                </entry>
```

and we should create a class

```
 CustomSignatureAction extends SignatureAction {
```

and override  features which different with fist signature